# TSQL XML Parsing and creating xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a tool which I now will be creating reports for using the data I have. I am currently working on a year to date report and need to pull the numbers for that.

My goal is to have an XML output of each of the months in the current year with their totals.

Here is what the XML currently looks like with my select statement:

```
<root>
    <data>
        <classXML>
          <courses>
            <class>
              <classTitle>Arts and Crafts</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>100</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>30</bookCost>
              <classTotal>130</classTotal>
            </class>
            <class>
              <classTitle>Paper 101</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>320</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>211</bookCost>
              <classTotal>531</classTotal>
            </class>
            <class>
              <classTitle>Introduction to Pencils</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>210</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>291</bookCost>
              <classTotal>501</classTotal>
            </class>
            <class>
              <classTitle>Intermediate Folding</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>110</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>22</bookCost>
              <classTotal>132</classTotal>
            </class>
            <class>
              <classTitle>Advanced Jumprope</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>11</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>22</bookCost>
              <classTotal>33</classTotal>
            </class>
            <grandTotal>1327</grandTotal>
          </courses>
        </classXML>
        <reimbursementDate>08/01/2014</reimbursementDate>
        </data>
        <data>
        <classXML>
          <courses>
            <class>
              <classTitle>dsfgfdsg</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>44</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>44</bookCost>
              <classTotal>88</classTotal>
            </class>
            <grandTotal>88</grandTotal>
          </courses>
        </classXML>
        <reimbursementDate>05/31/2014</reimbursementDate>
    </data>
</root>
```

And my stored procedure:

```
SELECT 
   A.[classXML],
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.[reimbursementDate], 101) as reimbursementDate
FROM   
   tuitionSubmissions as A
WHERE 
   A.[status] = 'Approved' 
   AND YEAR(A.[reimbursementDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
FOR XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

As you can see, the column `classXML` stores that data in XML format with all of the classes they are enrolled in with their costs.

So I need to loop over the XML and create an output that is just numbers to assist with my reporting.

Here is my desired outcome:

```
<results>
   <dataSet>
      <month>8</month>
      <year>2014</year>
      <tuitionTotal>500</tuitionTotal>
      <booksTotal>200</booksTotal>
      <grandTotal>700</grandTotal>
   </dataSet>
   <dataSet>
      <month>9</month>
      <year>2014</year>
      <tuitionTotal>100</tuitionTotal>
      <booksTotal>500</booksTotal>
      <grandTotal>600</grandTotal>
   </dataSet>
</results>
```

Comment: I would just study up on manipulating XML results here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx

Comment: I am having trouble getting a sum of one of the pieces of data from the XML. I need to loop over the main nodes /data/classXML/class and then get the sum of each of the tuitionTotal values. Once I can figure out how to do one it should be pretty straight forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sum Function (XQuery)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175504.aspx) to do the aggregation against your XML column.

I put the query against the XML in a cross apply so you don't have to do the same XQuery twice just to calculate `grandTotal`.

You should also change your predicate against `reimbursementDate` so it may use and index to find the rows.

```sql
select datepart(month, T.reimbursementDate) as month,
       datepart(year, T.reimbursementDate) as year,
       S.tuitionTotal,
       S.booksTotal,
       S.tuitionTotal + S.booksTotal as grandTotal
from dbo.tuitionSubmissions as T
  cross apply (
              select T.classXML.value('sum(/courses/class/tuitionCost/text())', 'int') as tuitionTotal,
                     T.classXML.value('sum(/courses/class/bookCost/text())', 'int') as booksTotal
              ) as S
where T.status = 'Approved' and
      T.reimbursementDate >= '20140101' and
      T.reimbursementDate < '20150101'
for xml path('dataSet'), root('results'), type
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/adb85/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DocH INT
DECLARE @DOC XML = '
<root>
    <data>
        <classXML>
          <courses>
            <class>
              <classTitle>Arts and Crafts</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>100</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>30</bookCost>
              <classTotal>130</classTotal>
            </class>
            <class>
              <classTitle>Paper 101</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>320</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>211</bookCost>
              <classTotal>531</classTotal>
            </class>
            <class>
              <classTitle>Introduction to Pencils</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>210</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>291</bookCost>
              <classTotal>501</classTotal>
            </class>
            <class>
              <classTitle>Intermediate Folding</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>110</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>22</bookCost>
              <classTotal>132</classTotal>
            </class>
            <class>
              <classTitle>Advanced Jumprope</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>11</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>22</bookCost>
              <classTotal>33</classTotal>
            </class>
            <grandTotal>1327</grandTotal>
          </courses>
        </classXML>
        <reimbursementDate>08/01/2014</reimbursementDate>
        </data>
        <data>
        <classXML>
          <courses>
            <class>
              <classTitle>dsfgfdsg</classTitle>
              <tuitionCost>44</tuitionCost>
              <bookCost>44</bookCost>
              <classTotal>88</classTotal>
            </class>
            <grandTotal>88</grandTotal>
          </courses>
        </classXML>
        <reimbursementDate>05/31/2014</reimbursementDate>
    </data>
</root>'
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocH OUTPUT, @DOC

SELECT
      MONTH(reimbursementDate) AS month
    , YEAR(reimbursementDate) AS year
    , SUM(tuitionCost) AS tuitionTotal, SUM(bookCost) AS bookTotal, SUM(tuitionCost+bookCost) AS grandTotal
FROM OPENXML(@DocH,'/root/data/classXML/courses/class') WITH (
    classTitle varchar(40) 'classTitle'
    , tuitionCost INT 'tuitionCost'
    , bookCost INT 'bookCost'
    , reimbursementDate date '../../../reimbursementDate'
    )
GROUP BY      MONTH(reimbursementDate)
    , YEAR(reimbursementDate)
FOR XML PATH ('dataset')
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocH;
```